# Não consigo recuperar o JSON no jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Não estou conseguindo exibir o `uf` na seguinte situação:

```
$.post("<?php echo site_url('Welcome/viacep'); ?>",
    {cep: cep}, 
   function(dados){
       alert(dados.uf); 
    }, 
    'json'
);
```

Mas quando eu mudo o alert para `alert(dados)`, o JSON aparece completo.

O que será que eu estou fazendo errado?

Comment: como está retornando o seu json?

Comment: http://viacep.com.br/ws/30626620/json/{
  "cep": "30626-620",
  "logradouro": "Rua Joaquim Teixeira Dias",
  "complemento": "",
  "bairro": "Cardoso (Barreiro)",
  "localidade": "Belo Horizonte",
  "uf": "MG",
  "unidade": "",
  "ibge": "3106200",
  "gia": ""
}

Answer (score 0):

Possivelmente tens de fazer *parse* do json:

```
$.post("<?php echo site_url('Welcome/viacep'); ?>", {cep: cep}, 
    function(response){ 
        var dados = JSON.parse(response);
        alert(dados.uf);
    }
, 'json' );
```

Comment: Quando eu chamo o JSON.parse, aí é que não funciona nada.

Comment: Meu json está chegando assim:

Comment: http://viacep.com.br/ws/30626620/json/{
  "cep": "30626-620",
  "logradouro": "Rua Joaquim Teixeira Dias",
  "complemento": "",
  "bairro": "Cardoso (Barreiro)",
  "localidade": "Belo Horizonte",
  "uf": "MG",
  "unidade": "",
  "ibge": "3106200",
  "gia": ""
}

Comment: aqui deu tudo certo.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa converter esse JSON que foi recebido como texto para um `Object`. Você pode usar o [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), do JavaScript nativo mesmo, da seguinte forma:

```
let obj = JSON.parse(dados);
```

A manipulação você usa o `obj` ao invés do `dados`.

```
alert(obj.cep);
```

---

O jQuery também tem uma função para deserializar JSON, [`$.parseJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/),  mas é considerada obsoleta, então você pode usar a do JavaScript puro como no exemplo dado anteriormente.

> As of jQuery 3.0, $.parseJSON is deprecated. To parse JSON strings use
>   the native JSON.parse method instead. [Fonte](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

```
$.getJSON("//viacep.com.br/ws/"+ cep +"/json/?callback=?", function(dados) {

        if (!("erro" in dados)) {
            //Atualiza os campos com os valores da consulta.
            $("#logradouro").val(dados.logradouro);
            $("#bairro").val(dados.bairro);
        } //end if.
        else {
            //CEP pesquisado não foi encontrado.
            //limpa_formulário_cep();
            errosend("CEP não encontrado.");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Obrigado adventistaam! Funcionou perfeitamente.